# Error en consulta Sequelize SQL

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js

Tengo esta consulta:

```
           where: {
            $or: {
                $and: {
                    mes: mes,
                    any: any
                },
                $and: {
                    dia: 1,
                    mes: 1 + Number(mes),
                    any: any
                }
            }
        }
```

Trato de seleccionar los registros de un mes y año, más el primer día del mes siguiente.
Todo parece correcto. No hay error de compilación, pero en ejecución sí da un error como de sintaxis: syntax error near ",".

¿Alguien sabría por qué?

#### Actualización

La consulta que quiero pasar a Sequelize es la siguiente:

```
WHERE (`Partes`.`mes`=3 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017 
      OR `Partes`.`dia`=1 AND `Partes`.`mes`=4 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017)
      ORDER BY `fecha` ASC, `Comments`.`codigo` ASC;
```

Gracias.

Comment: Jota, he puesto la consulta de tu otra pregunta en esta. No hagas varias preguntas respecto al mismo tema porque es redundar. Ya he actualizado mi respuesta con esta última petición.

Comment: Esta herramienta es genial para crear tus sentencias SQL a ORM esta para casi todas las plataformas. https://pontaku-tools.com/english/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

veo que aun estas en esto, prueba de la siguiente manera.

```
where: Sequelize.or(
    Sequelize.and(
        {mes: mes},
        {anio: anio}
    ),
    Sequelize.and(
        {dia: 1},
        {mes: 1 + Number(mes)},
        {anio: anio}
    )
)
```

Comment: Ya lo había probado: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Quizzes.$or

Comment: @Jota tal vez se deba a la version de Sequelize, prueba utilizando las funciones Sequelize.or y Sequelize.and en lugar de $or y $and, tal como lo edite

Comment: tienes razón. Creo entonces que las respuestas de otros compañeros también son correctas, pero tú has dado con la clave. Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 2):

puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```
    where: {
        $or: {
            $and: {
                mes: mes,
                any: any
            },
            $and: {
                dia: 1,
                mes: (1 + Number(mes)),
                any: any
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sigue igual: error: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: que hace la función Number?

Comment: @Maskter `Number` es un objeto que sirve como envolvente para los números primitivos, relaciónalo a `int` e `Integer` de Java. También acepta números en forma de texto y devuelve un número de punto flotante.

Answer (score 1):

> Trato de seleccionar los registros de un mes y año, más el primer día del mes siguiente

Entonces, ¿para qué usas `OR` si te basta con `AND`? Además, el helper `$or` de Sequelize acepta un array, no un objeto literal. Tu consulta se simplica así:

```
where: {
  mes, anio,
  $and: {
    anio,
    dia: 1,
    mes: mes + 1
  }
}
```

---

Asumo que `mes` es un entero por eso lo sumo tal cual. En caso sea un string (raro porque en `dia` pasas un entero), entonces deja el `Number(mes)`.

---

#### Actualización

La consulta que has puesto en la actualización de tu pregunta se traduce a:

```
Model.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      {
        $and: {
          mes: 3,
          anio: 2017
        }
      },
      {
        $and: {
          dia: 1,
          mes: 4,
          anio: 2017
        }
      }
    ],
    order: 'fecha codigo ASC'
  }
})
.then(models => {

});
```

El primer `$and` se traduce a:

```
mes = 3 AND anio = 2017
```

El segundo `$and` se traduce a:

```
dia = 1 AND mes = 4 AND anio = 2017
```

Y el `$or` que los envuelve se interpreta como:

```
WHERE
  mes = 3 AND anio = 2017 OR
  dia = 1 AND mes = 4 AND anio = 2017
```

Comment: Sigue el error: syntax error at or near "1".

Comment: ¿Estás usando Typescript? La palabra `any` está reservada en Typescript por ende, no puedes usarla. En caso uses JavaScript **no hay razón lógica** para que te muestre dicho error. ¿Qué contenido tiene `any`?

Comment: ya lo había pensado, pero no lo he cambiado. lo cambiaré por anio a ver. contiene el año seleccionado. Aunque no lo tengo claro que sea eso, porque en una consulta simple no me da problemas usar 'any'. De todas formas lo cambio por 'anio' y a ver. Gracias.

Comment: Gustavo, ya he hecho el cambio, y ahora más misterio. Hace bien la consulta, pero no devuelve nada. La consola dice: **  WHERE (`Partes`.`mes`=3 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017 AND `Partes`.`dia`=1 AND `Partes`.`mes`=4 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017)**. Parece  que voy por buen camino, pero algo falta y se me escapa qué puede ser. Si conoces el problema te agradezco el comentario.

Comment: La consulta correcta en SQL sería: WHERE (`Partes`.`mes`=3 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017 
      OR `Partes`.`dia`=1 AND `Partes`.`mes`=4 AND `Partes`.`anio`=2017)
      ORDER BY `fecha` ASC, `Comments`.`codigo` ASC;

Comment: Ya la he puesto en tu pregunta y he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Hay algún error porque **  $and: {
19:28:29 web.1  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  Tu consulta la he puesto en un where:{tu_consulta}.

Comment: Sí, ¿no lo viste? fue un error de sintaxis, supongo ya lo corregiste. De igual manera, actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Sí lo había corregido, y también probado. Ahora da este error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Quizzes.$or.

Comment: Por cierto mueve el `order` fuera del where. El error último que comentas te está diciendo que Sequelize está tomando `$or` como si fuese una columna. Muy raro la verdad.

Comment: Ya había sacado order del where. Y sí es raro, y además solo da el error en ejecución.

Comment: tu propuesta seguro que es correcta. El problema era la versión de Sequelize. Muchas gracias.